# T-SQL Comparison of Min and Max Values Over Time

Tags: sql, sql-server

Working in SQL Server, I have a table with 4 columns

- AccountId
- AccountName
- SubscriptionAmt
- DateKey

It lists each company's `SubscriptionAmt` by month (`DateKey`, i.e 201801) as they change over time.

I want to write one select statement including

```
AccountId, AccountName, EarliestSubscriptionAmt, LatestSubscriptionAmt, Difference
```

I know the effort below is not correct. I know I have to do some kind of partition over in the sub queries but I cant put my finger on it

Any help is appreciated

```
SELECT 
    [Account ID],
    [Account Name],
    b.EarlySub,
    c.LatestSub,
    (c.LatestSub - b.EarlySub / b.EarlySub) * 100 as PercentageChange
FROM 
    SubTable AS
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT
         [Account ID],
         SubscriptionAmt AS EarlySub
     FROM 
         SubTable
     WHERE 
         DateKey = MIN(DateKey)) AS b ON a.[Account ID] = b.[Account ID]
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT
         [Account ID],
         SubscriptionAmt AS LatestSub
     FROM 
         SubTable
     WHERE 
         DateKey = MAX(DateKey)) AS c ON a.[Account ID] = c.[Account ID]
```

Sample Data:

```
AccountId   AccountName   SubscriptionAmt   DateKey  
----------------------------------------------------
    1       Bob's Store        100          201701
    1       Bob's Store        200          201702
    1       Bob's Store        300          201703
    1       Bob's Store        400          201704
```

Desired Results:

```
AccountId  AccountName   EarliestSubAmt  LatestSubAmt  PercentageChange
------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1      Bob's Store       100             400           300%
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff done ... apologies for overlooking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FULL demonstration:

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE
(
AccountId VARCHAR(50),
AccountName VARCHAR(50),
SubscriptionAmt INT,
DateKey VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @TABLE
VALUES('1','Bob''s Store','100','201701'),('1','Bob''s Store','200','201702'),('1','Bob''s Store','300','201703'),('1','Bob''s Store','400','201704')

;
WITH CTE
AS
(
 SELECT  AccountId,
         AccountName,
         SubscriptionAmt,
         ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY AccountId,AccountName ORDER BY CAST(DateKey+'01' as DATE)) as ForMin,
         ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY AccountId,AccountName ORDER BY CAST(DateKey+'01' as DATE) DESC) as ForMAX                      
        FROM @TABLE
)
SELECT A.AccountId,
       A.AccountName,
       A.SubscriptionAmt as EarliestSubAmt,
       B.SubscriptionAmt as LatestSubAmt,
       CAST(((B.SubscriptionAmt - A.SubscriptionAmt)/A.SubScriptionAmt ) as varchar(50)) + '%' as PercentageChange
FROM CTE as A
INNER JOIN CTE as B
ON A.AccountId = B.AccountId
AND A.AccountName = B.AccountName
WHERE A.ForMin = 1 AND B.ForMAX = 1
```

Comment: Thank you for this BUT I am looking for the SubscriptionAmt of the MIN(DateKey) and the SubscriptionAmt of the MAx(DateKey) per Account ... I added data sample and desired results in the question as advised

Comment: wait, based on your desired output, it should be calculated based on SubscriptionAmt ? And that is not a date column? just a `int`?

Comment: yes ... i am looking for the difference between the first SubscriptionAmt and the last SubscriptionAmt ... yes it is just an int

Comment: Updated:) please check it

Comment: I can tell that isn't it because there is no mention of SubscriptionAmt. I am not looking for the MIN/MAX DateKey value. I am looking for the SubscriptionAmt value based on the MIN and MAX DateKey values.

Comment: So the MAX(DateKey) may not have a latest SubscriptionAmt in your table?

Comment: Updated my dumb way to do that

Comment: this worked. the percentage change formula was incorrect but that was easy to change. Thank you!!!

(B.SubscriptionAmt - A.SubscriptionAmt)/A.SubScriptionAmt

Comment: Glad to know that, @hansolo, edited the answer. -----by The First Jedi

Answer (score 1):

you can get the Min and Max amounts by first getting the min date and the max date per account id using outer apply, then using a case expression to get the min or max amounts

```
select  [AccountId], [AccountName],
        MIN(CASE WHEN DateKey = MinDateKey THEN SubscriptionAmt END) as EarliestSubAmt,
        MAX(CASE WHEN DateKey = MaxDateKey THEN SubscriptionAmt END) as LatestSubAmt

from    SubTable s
outer apply (
        select Min(DateKey) MinDateKey, Max(DateKey) MaxDateKey from SubTable t where s.AccountId = t.AccountId
) t
group by [AccountId], [AccountName]
```

you can wrap all of this to get the percent change.

```
select  *,
        ((LatestSubAmt-EarliestSubAmt)/EarliestSubAmt) * 100 as PercentageChange
from    (
            select  [AccountId], [AccountName],
                    MIN(CASE WHEN DateKey = MinDateKey THEN SubscriptionAmt END) as EarliestSubAmt,
                    MAX(CASE WHEN DateKey = MaxDateKey THEN SubscriptionAmt END) as LatestSubAmt
            from    SubTable s
            outer apply (
                    select Min(DateKey) MinDateKey, Max(DateKey) MaxDateKey from SubTable t where s.AccountId = t.AccountId
            ) t
            group by [AccountId], [AccountName]
) s
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use below query . I have considered Account ID as key value for each store and it will not be duplicated. Please test before implementing into any system.

```
--Data Prep
create table #Test (
        AccountId int,
        AccountName varchar(max),
        SubscriptionAmt int,
        DateKey int
        )

insert into #Test
    Select 1,'Bobs Store',100,201701
    union
    select 1,'Bobs Store',200,201702
    union
    select 1,'Bobs Store',300,201703
    union
    select 1,'Bobs Store',400,201704

--Actual code ****************************************************

select *,
    ROW_NUMBER() over(Partition by Accountid order by datekey asc) MinAm,
    ROW_NUMBER() over(Partition by Accountid order by datekey desc) MaxAm into #Final
 from #Test

Select *,
        ((LatestSubAmt-EarliestSubAmt)/EarliestSubAmt)*100 as PercentageChange
From (
  select 
        AccountId,
        AccountName,
        (select SubscriptionAmt from #Final f2 where f1.AccountId=f2.AccountId and f2.MinAm=1) EarliestSubAmt,
        (select SubscriptionAmt from #Final f2 where f1.AccountId=f2.AccountId and f2.MaxAm=1) LatestSubAmt
  from #Final f1
  Where MinAm=1) A
```

--********************************************************

If you don't want to use sub query

```
Select Distinct Accountid,
      AccountName,
      sum(case when minAm=1 then SubscriptionAmt else 0 END) over (Partition by Accountid) EarliestSubAmt ,
      sum(case when maxam=1 then SubscriptionAmt else 0 END) over (Partition by Accountid) LatestSubAmt,
      ((sum(case when maxam=1 then SubscriptionAmt else 0 END) over (Partition by Accountid)-sum(case when minAm=1 then SubscriptionAmt else 0 END) over (Partition by Accountid))
      /sum(case when minAm=1 then SubscriptionAmt else 0 END) over (Partition by Accountid))*100 PercentageChange
FRom (
select *,
    ROW_NUMBER() over(Partition by Accountid order by datekey asc) MinAm,
    ROW_NUMBER() over(Partition by Accountid order by datekey desc) MaxAm 
 from #Test
 )A
```